# create pandas dataframe from 27 millions rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 27 millions tuples and now I want to create a dataframe from this tuple, but the problem is, it is taking too much time and system gets stuck.

Data in a single tuple is `('C0000005', 'RB', 'C0036775', '')`
and  and the list is tablelist which contains appx. 27 million rows and this is how I'm creating the dataframe.

```
df_table = pd.DataFrame(tablelist,columns= ['a','b','c','d'])
```

how do I create dataframe in efficient way?

Comment: Have you tried doing it via a CSV file?

Comment: Do you absolutely *need* a dataframe? Is there a way to accomplish your task without one?

Comment: @not_a_robot a tabular would be nice, but is there any other method for fast processing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your machine doesn't swap.

Here is my timing:

```
In [175]: l = [('C0000005', 'RB', 'C0036775', '')] * 27000000

In [176]: len(l)
Out[176]: 27000000

In [177]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(l, columns=list('abcd'))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.95 s per loop
```

---

```
In [179]: df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=list('abcd'))

In [180]: df.shape
Out[180]: (27000000, 4)

In [181]: df.memory_usage()
Out[181]:
Index           80
a        216000000
b        216000000
c        216000000
d        216000000
dtype: int64

In [182]: df.memory_usage().sum()
Out[182]: 864000080

In [183]: df.memory_usage().sum()/1024**3
Out[183]: 0.8046627789735794
```